Why is there a difference between accessing through Selenium and Chrome browser?
I'm making a program to collect information on the AliExpress site in Korea for learning. I filled in my User-agent information and turned on Chrome with selenium. However, despite the same link, different products appear from when I enter Chrome directly and when I enter with selenium. Why does this happen? Is there a solution?
keyword = "모니터"
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('user-agent:myagent')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    all_data = []
    for page in range(1, 2):
        url = f"https://ko.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-{keyword}.html?page={page}&g=y&SearchText={keyword}"
        print(f"Extracting data from page {page}...")
        driver.get(url)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would control for the profile first.  Create a profile manually and manually browse the site using it.  Then set Selenium to use the same profile and compare results.
